# Regular Matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

My homework will create a program that check the numbers in an array with a given pattern. Program must take the matrix dimensions and terms in the matrix as arguments from command line. For example  program name is `myProg.exe` and we want to check a 2x3 dimensioned matrix with (maximum dimension limit is 20x20):

```
1 2 3

4 5 6
```

Then I will run your program as.

The program will check a special matrix pattern and prints out `ACCEPTABLE` or `NOT MATCH` according to the values we put from the console. The Special Pattern: In a row major representation the cells of the matrix must obey this rule. Some terms of the matrix must be sum or product of the neighbor cells. In row major representation the sum and product operations are placed as given in the examples. Sum and Product cells follows each other with one free cells. For Odd rows the sequence starts with free cells and in Even Rows the sequence starts with Sum or Product cell.

My code is here:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <sstream>

 using namespace std;

static  int iter = 0;
static unsigned int sat=3, sut=2;
bool ok = false;
int *accepted;
int *array;


 string isAcceptable(int mat[]) {

    int l, co = 0;
    bool operation = false;
    int mat2[sat][sut];

    for (int i = 0; i < sat; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sut; j++) {
            mat2[i][j] = mat[co];
            co++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sat; i++) {

        if (i % 2 == 0)
            l = 1;
        else
            l = 0;

        for (int j = l; j < sut; j += 2) {

            int totalProduct;

            if (!operation) {
                totalProduct = 0;

                if (j > 0)
                    totalProduct += mat2[i][j - 1];
                if (j < sut - 1)
                    totalProduct += mat2[i][j + 1];
                if (i > 0)
                    totalProduct += mat2[i - 1][j];
                if (i < sat - 1)
                    totalProduct += mat2[i + 1][j];

            } else {
                totalProduct = 1;

                if (j > 0)
                    totalProduct *= mat2[i][j - 1];
                if (j < sut - 1)
                    totalProduct *= mat2[i][j + 1];
                if (i > 0)
                    totalProduct *= mat2[i - 1][j];
                if (i < sat - 1)
                    totalProduct *= mat2[i + 1][j];
            }

            if (mat2[i][j] != totalProduct)
                return "NOT MATCH";

            operation = !operation;

        }
    }
    return "ACCEPTABLE";
}

    void change(int index1, int index2) {

    int temp;

    temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;

    iter++;

}

 void combine(int mat[], int len) {

    if(ok)
    return;

    array = new int[len];
    *array = *mat;


    if (len <= sat * sut) {

        for (int i = len; i < sat * sut - 1; i++) {

            for (int j = i; j < sat * sut; j++) {

                combine(array, len + 1);
                change(i, j);

                if (isAcceptable(array) == ("ACCEPTABLE")) {
                    int accepted[sat*sut];
                    *accepted = *array;

                    ok = true;
                    return;
                }



            }

        }
    } else
        return;
}

string isAcceptableCombine(int mat[]) {

    combine(mat, 6);

    if (ok)
    {
        cout<< " TRUE Sequense";
        return "ACCEPTABLE";
    }
    else
        cout<< " FALSE Sequense";
        return "NOT MATCH";
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {



int matris[] = {1,2,1,4,1,6};

isAcceptableCombine(matris);

}
```

My code's result is always returning `TRUE Sequence`.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Run in a debugger, and step through the code line by line, it should help you find out what's happening.

Comment: Also, there are some dubious code in the snippet you show us, like this assignment `*array = *mat`, that will cope the first value of `mat` to the first value of `array`, and leave the rest of the entries in `array` uninitialized (which will give you [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since uninitialized data is indeterminate).

Comment: Oh, and it's even worse than I saw first, since in the first (non-recursive) call to `combine` the argument `len` is zero and that means you are allocating a zero-size array, so writing to any index in `array`is *also* undefined behavior since it's out of bounds.

Comment: Where does `array` come from in `change` and `combined`? (a terrible name btw, as `array` in conjunction with that `using namespace std;` is rife to introduce ambiguity,

Comment: edited again, array is global array. i assigned mat method to array in combine.